# Amount of people that live in Buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, buffer

[image]

I am fairly new to Arcgis.

I need to create a buffer for each blue Area (which I can do) with 5km and then get the amount of people that live in this buffer. Assumption is that people live normally distributed in the green Areas. I already have the amount of people per sqkm.

Comment: Use the Clip geoprocessing tool http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm but you will need to re-caluate  your area after the clip to get the average of per per area

Answer (score 3):

1. Clip the population data with the buffers
2. Dissolve the clip output and summarize the 'SUM' of your population attribute

The above solves the original question that was asked.  With additional clarification from OP, here is the process to extrapolate population per square km from the base population data to the buffers:

1. Add a field for Area_sqkm to the buffers and calculate the area for each buffer
2. Intersect buffers and population data
3. Add a field for population to the intersect result
4. To fill the population field, divide PopulationPerSqKm/BufferArea

Comment: May have asked unprecise, but I need to get the population for each buffer by itself. I have now created around 80 buffer for each blue area and the next step would be that I can get the area of each green and arcmap then automatically gets the amount of people that live in each buffer by calculating the area and then the number of people per sqkm2. So if 10 people live in 10sqkm and the buffer would cover 1sqkm, arcmap would add 1 person as an attribute

Comment: Will you please put this information into your question?  It is very unclear and your comment clarifies it.  I've edited my answer.